Reverse query users with given role in Liberty or OpenLiberty
Java EE security model provides interfaces to query if the current logged user has a given role (either declaratively through @RolesAllowed or @RolesDenied, or programatically like EJBContext.isCallerInRole).
Now our app needs to query the user registry the other way: for a given role, list all users which will succeed in invoking methods guarded by @RolesAllowed(given-role) (or will pass a test isCallerInRole(given-role)). The idea is to present such a list to the end user, in case they can't do some operation himself; we'd like to give them directions on who can.
I don't expect to find anything like that in Java EE security model. But maybe it is possible to do it in a custom way in Liberty (Open or IBM).
Our servers are configured using ldapRegistry, but if there is something more general for any possible registry it would be preferred.
Also the question for "roles" goes through the indirection layer of role bindings (in our case, roles are bound to lists of groups). But maybe there is no solution to traverse that indirection layer reversely. A mean of querying the LDAP for users in a list of groups will also suffice (though again, the more general approach is preferrable).
UPDATE
Using com.ibm.wsspi.security.registry.RegistryHelper I could find the list of users, like this:
import com.ibm.websphere.security.UserRegistry;
import com.ibm.wsspi.security.registry.RegistryHelper;

{
  UserRegistry registry = RegistryHelper.getUserRegistry(null);
  List<String> users = registry.getUsersForGroup("GROUP-NAME", 100).getList();

  // now users contains strings such as:
  // "CN=userid,CN=Users,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=net"
}

Almost there. BUT...
The problem with the previous code is that UserRegistry::getUsersForGroup is deprecated for removal.
I've tried some other methods of UserRegistry but its interface is very simple, basically every method return either boolean, or String or Result (which bears a List<String>).
There is nothing I could use to navigate to a group, then to members of it (to compute the member closure).
I'm still searching for an answer to the problem. And given that it's too hard to find anything touching the subject, I'm now wondering why it is not more common a problem? Maybe what I want implies in some security hole?
